# React unit test: Tepeerror: data.filter is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

Here I am using `.fiter()` to get the respective data. But during the `unit test` I am getting error of `data.filter()` is not a function. Any suggestion how can this be resolved. I tried with many ways but didn't able to get this fixed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**.tsx code snippet**

[image]

**.test.tsx**

```
describe('Org Profile Component', () => {
    afterAll(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks();
    });
    let component;
    let store: Store<any>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const initialState = {
            props: [
                {
                    spaceDonation: {
                        history: {}, 
                        cId: '11',
                    } 
                }
            ]
        }
        store = mockStore(initialState);
        const queryClient = new QueryClient();
        component = mount(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                        <Events {...initialState}/>
                    </QueryClientProvider>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        )
        const node = component.find('Events').instance();
        node.setState({
            props:[
                {
                    spaceDonation: {
                        history: {}, 
                        cId: '13',
                    } 
                }
            ]
        })
    });
    
    it('Should render without crash', async () => {
        await act(() => {
            expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
        })
    });
    
});
```

Comment: Check the value of `storeData` . My guess is it is undefined.

Comment: Thank you @ccheneson for your time. It is undefined or empty at the first place. we are getting data after rendering..

Comment: const [storeData, setStoreData] = useState([]);
    const mutation = useMutation((key: any) => service.fetchDashboardDetails(key));
    useEffect(() => {
        if (mutation.isSuccess) { setStoreData(mutation.data); }
    }, [mutation.isSuccess]);
    useEffect(() => {
        mutation.mutate({Num: 1234})
    }, []);

Comment: Check the value of `mutation.data` if it is undefined when `setStoreData(mutation.data)` (I'm myself new in TS/React, so my help will be limited :) )

Comment: yes it is undefined first.
`mutation.data
undefined`
`mutation.data
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: So that's why you have that error. `filter` is a method on an array and since it is undefined, you have to investigate why mutation.data is undefined in `setStoreData(mutation.data);` (storeData is correctly initialized to [] in the `useState`)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time :) I am trying if I can find the way. Thanks

Comment: One thing is `useMutation` works with `asynchronously` so this will be always `undefined` at first.

Comment: The best would be to provide a minimal reproducible example (MRE) in https://codesandbox.io for example.